# JQuery mobile dialog error SecurityError: The operation is insecure

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I use HTML and JQuery mobile for phonegap but when i test it use this code, it showing error SecurityError: The operation is insecure. F**or changepage function its working well**, why this is happend?

```
$.mobile.changePage( "#confirm", { 
        role: "dialog"
})
```

This is my Dialog HTML inside of index.html file

```
<div data-role="page" id="confirm">
      <div data-role="header" id="header">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="header-logo"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="header-bottom"></div>           
      </div>

      <div data-role="content" class="ui-content" id="logedin-view">
            <div class="border-logedin">
                <center><h3>Title Loged in Main</h3></center>
            </div>              
            <form id="codesend">
                <input type="text" id="code" class="input" placeholder="Code" required/>
            </form>
            <center>
                <button type="submit" form="codesend" id="code-send" class="input btn-submit" value="submit" data-role="none">Submit</button>
            </center>
            <a href="#index" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b ui-icon-back ui-btn-icon-left" data-rel="back">Go Back</a>
      </div>

      <div class="footer" data-role="footer">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case the problem was this line:

```
window.history.replaceState( state, state.title || document.title, href );
```

(in version 1.4.5 row 2954)

I'm not sure what it does, but after commenting it out, my code worked.

Answer (score -1):

Most of those issues are relating to the Same Origin Policy. Loading js files or css rules from a different domain may cause the problem.

When you test your code locally you may load additional files from cdn// or another remout server, this causes cross domain security error in jQuery scripts.

Comment: in my case "maybe" just one function that showing error, for other thats fine, this is make me confuse